# HTML How to check which browser is the html currently being viewed in?

Tags: html, browser

I am in need to know which is the current browser my website is being viewed on, because that way I know how to execute specific code for Images and CSS, stuff like that...

Comment: You shouldn't need to check for which browser beyond conditional comments for IE. Everything else is feature detection.

Comment: Yeah, I know they do feature detection but for example. 

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

CSS technique #1, says its good for all browsers except for some IE exceptions, so I would like to know when that browser is being called to use a different method. 

Ahh and what happens is that in Safari, Chrome, Mozilla my background image is being displayed, however in IE my image doesn't load at all giving me real problems on how the website is displayed.

Comment: ...and why isn't that obviously relevant information in your question?

Comment: @StevenHernandez: If you scroll that page down a bit, you'll see an IE hack, if you *really* want to go that route. Personally, I'd just use a large enough background image, centered. As a fallback condition to handle an increasingly out-of-date browser, that's not too bad. Depends on whether you're doing professional client work or not, of course, and - if so - how reasonable the client is.

Comment: It is a professional job for a client, the problem is he wanted it working on all Browsers, personally I understand IE is an out-of-date browser, in which i personally don't even acknowledge as one anymore i just use Chrome or Safari or Mozilla. 

However since he is a client I need to try to help him on his needs.

Thanks a lot, I'll work on that.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, you've been very helpful. :) Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your comments suggest that you only need IE detection, the best way I've seen of detecting IE for CSS purposes is used in the [HTML 5 Boilerplate project](http://html5boilerplate.com/), which uses a [technique by Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/):

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html>         <!--<![endif]-->
```

I'd recommend using the HTML5BP version:

```
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!-- Consider adding a manifest.appcache: h5bp.com/d/Offline -->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This is the code I was looking for I saw this before I just couldn't remember the exact code.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/) and [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/)

Comment: Note that Modernizer does not do anything by itself. You must write some JavaScript to use it. Otherwise, I give you +1!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the headsup, ill check Modernizer, seems pretty neat helping speed up Feature checking process.

Answer (score 1):

you can check the browser info with javascript embedded into html.

more details can e.g. be found here:

http://www.alanwood.net/demos/browserinfo.html

example code: (now works for sure)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>test</title></head>
<body>
<script>
alert(navigator.userAgent);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are both PHP and JavaScript classes/functions for this. All you have to do is google for the respective one and then use it to your liking on a per browser basis. You could even go a step higher and do it based on .htaccess but over all depends on what your doing with what where when why etc..

All in all though generally speaking short of some styling issues, or some specific client side scripting issues almost anything you do with just standard html will work fine cross all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to inspect the [`navigator.userAgent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp) property. There are a few Javascript libraries that you can download that will do this parsing for you. However, you should know that trying to determine the browser type by parsing the user agent string is incredibly unreliable.

If you're trying to toggle behavior based on browser capabilities you should instead check for those specific features and see if they are enabled in the current browser. You can start by reading [this post on QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html).

Someone else mentioned [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) which is just a library that does the feature detection for you. This is much more reliable than inspecting the browser's user agent.

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath APIs to determine the browser engine:

```
//Gecko
var gecko = (!!window.XPathExpression === true) && "gecko";
//Trident
var trident = (!!window.XPathEvaluator === false && !!window.XPathExpression === false) && "trident";
//WebKit
var webkit = (!!window.XPathEvaluator === true && !!window.XPathExpression === false) && "webkit";

var browser = (String(gecko)+String(trident)+String(webkit)).replace(/false/g,"");
```

Use `document.documentMode` to detect which mode IE is using as well.

**References**

- [Windows Internet Explorer Platform APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772402)
- [Mozilla Source Code Directory Structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Source_Code/Directory_structure)
- [MDN: Web API Index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Index)
- [WebKitJS](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkitjs)
- [Planet Webkit](https://planet.webkit.org/)
- [Web specifications support in Opera](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/)
- [Details for Document API - Microsoft Edge Development](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/apireference/interfaces/document/)